# Error en bucle de listas

Tags: c, punteros

La funcion de abajo del todo, `extra`, no funciona correctamente, antes de llegar al primer `if` después del `while` se me cierra el programa. ¿A qué se puede deber el error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct nodo{
    struct nodo *ant;
    struct nodo *sig;
    char nombreUsuario[30];
    char tw[140];
};

struct listaDoble{
    struct nodo *primero;
    struct nodo *ultimo;
};
void addOrd(struct listaDoble *lista);
void visLista(struct listaDoble *lista);
void eliminar(struct listaDoble *lista);
void verInversa(struct listaDoble *lista);
void extra(struct listaDoble lista);
int main() {
    struct listaDoble lista;
    int opc;
    lista.primero=NULL;
    lista.ultimo=NULL;

    do{
        opc=menu();
        switch(opc){
            case 1:
                addOrd(&lista);
                break;
            case 2:
                eliminar(&lista);
                break;
            case 3:
                visLista(&lista);
                break;
            case 4:
                verInversa(&lista);
                break;
            case 5:
                extra(lista);
                break;
        }
    }while(opc!=0);

}

int menu(){
    int opc;
    printf("Introduce una opcion :\n");
    printf("1) Insertar tweet \n");
    printf("2) Eliminar tweet. \n");
    printf("3) Recorrer lista. \n");
    printf("4) Recorrer lista al reves. \n");
    printf("5) Estadisticas. \n");
    printf("0) Salir\n");
    scanf("%d",&opc);
    return opc;
}


void eliminar(struct listaDoble *lista){
    struct nodo *recorre, *anterior, *siguiente;
    char nombre[30];
    recorre = lista->primero;
    int aux=1, i=1;
    if (recorre == NULL){
        printf("La lista esta vacia");
        return;
    }

    anterior=recorre->ant;
    siguiente=recorre->sig;

    printf("Introduce el nombre del usuario :\n"); fflush(stdin); gets(nombre);

    while(aux==1){
        while(recorre!=NULL && strcmp(nombre, recorre->nombreUsuario)!=0){
            anterior=recorre;
            recorre=recorre->sig;
            if(recorre!=NULL){
                siguiente=recorre->sig;
            }

        }
        if(recorre==NULL){

            printf("No se ha encontrado ese usuario.\n");       
            return;
        }
        else if(anterior==NULL && siguiente==NULL){
            lista->primero=NULL;
            lista->ultimo=NULL;
            free(recorre);
            return;
        }
        else if(siguiente==NULL){
                anterior->sig=NULL;
                lista->ultimo=anterior;
                return;
        }
        else if(anterior==NULL){
            siguiente=recorre->sig;
            siguiente->ant=NULL;
            lista->primero=siguiente;

            }
        else{
            anterior->sig=siguiente;
            siguiente->ant=anterior;
        }

        if(strcmp(siguiente->nombreUsuario, nombre)==0 && recorre!=NULL){
            free(recorre);
            recorre = lista->primero;
            anterior=recorre->ant;
            siguiente=recorre->sig;
            i=0;
        }
        else{
            return;
        }


    }   
}


void addOrd(struct listaDoble *lista){
    struct nodo *temp,*recorre,*anterior;

    temp=(struct nodo *) malloc (sizeof(struct nodo));

    printf("Introduce el nombre de usuario: \n"); fflush(stdin); gets(temp->nombreUsuario);
    printf("Introduce el tweet: \n"); fflush(stdin); gets(temp->tw);
    temp->ant=NULL;
    temp->sig=NULL;
    recorre=lista->primero;

    if(recorre==NULL){
        lista->primero=temp;
        lista->ultimo=temp;
        return;
    }
    else if(strcmp(temp->nombreUsuario, recorre->nombreUsuario)<=0){
        temp->sig=recorre;
        recorre->ant=temp;
        lista->primero=temp;
        return;
    }
    else{
        while(recorre!=NULL && strcmp(temp->nombreUsuario, recorre->nombreUsuario)>=0){
            anterior=recorre;
            recorre=recorre->sig;
        }
        if(recorre==NULL){
            anterior->sig=temp;
            temp->ant=anterior;
            lista->ultimo=temp;
        }
        else{
            anterior->sig=temp;
            temp->ant=anterior;
            temp->sig=recorre;
            recorre->ant=temp;
        }
    }
}

void visLista(struct listaDoble *lista){
    struct nodo *recorre;

    recorre=lista->primero;
    if(recorre==NULL){
        printf("La lista esta vacia.\n");
        return;
    }
    while(recorre!=NULL){
        printf("%s:  ", recorre->nombreUsuario);
        printf("%s\n", recorre->tw);
        recorre=recorre->sig;

    }
}
void verInversa(struct listaDoble *lista){
    struct nodo *recorre;

    recorre=lista->ultimo;
    if(recorre==NULL){
        printf("La lista esta vacia. \n");
        return;
    }
    while(recorre != NULL){
        printf("%s:  ", recorre->nombreUsuario);
        printf("%s\n", recorre->tw);
        recorre=recorre->ant;
    }
}

void extra(struct listaDoble lista){
    struct nodo *recorre, *siguiente, *anterior;
    float i, contUser, contMedia;
    recorre=lista.primero;

    if(recorre==NULL){
        printf("No hay tweets");
        return;
    }
    siguiente=recorre->sig;
    anterior=recorre->ant;

    contUser=1;
    contMedia=1;
    while(recorre!=NULL){

        if(strcmp(anterior->nombreUsuario, recorre->nombreUsuario) == 0 || strcmp(siguiente->nombreUsuario,recorre->nombreUsuario) == 0){

            contMedia++;
        }
        else{
            contUser++;
            contMedia++;
        }

        anterior=recorre;
        recorre=recorre->sig;

        if(recorre!=NULL){

        siguiente=recorre->sig;
        }
    }
    printf("El total de usuarios es de : %f y la media es de %f tweets por usuario", contUser, contMedia/contUser);
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar que error estás obteniendo?

Answer (score 1):

```
void extra(struct listaDoble lista){
    struct nodo *recorre, *siguiente, *anterior;
    float i, contUser, contMedia;
    recorre=lista.primero; // 1

    if(recorre==NULL){
        printf("No hay tweets");
        return;
    }
    siguiente=recorre->sig;
    anterior=recorre->ant; // 2

    contUser=1;
    contMedia=1;
    while(recorre!=NULL){

        if(strcmp(anterior->nombreUsuario, recorre->nombreUsuario) == 0 ||  ... ){ // 3
```

Siguiendo los comentarios:

1. `recorre` apunta al primer elemento de la lista
2. `anterior` apunta a `NULL`
3. intentas acceder a `NULL->nombreUsuario` -> acceso a memoria no direccionada por tu aplicación.

Al llegar al punto 3 tienes todas las papeletas para que el Sistema Operativo, si es mínimamente moderno, mate tu aplicación para evitar la corrupción de la memoria.

No estaría de más comprobar el estado de `anterior` y de `siguiente` antes de utilizarlos (sí, los dos porque cuando estés en el último elemento de la lísta, `siguiente` apuntará a `NULL`):

```
if( anterior != NULL && strcmp(anterior->nombreUsuario, recorre->nombreUsuario) == 0 )
{
  // ...
}

if( siguiente != NULL && strcmp(siguiente->nombreUsuario,recorre->nombreUsuario) == 0 )
{
  // ...
}
```